# How to implement a middleware using object oriented design pattern in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, oop, design-patterns

I am new to an object-oriented design pattern. 
I just want to convert my **middleware** function and **models** to follow an object-oriented design pattern and use that throughout my code. So how would it be possible to implement??

**// sample middleware**

```
const isActivated = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email } = req.body
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    if (!user) {
      next(new Error('No such user is found!'))
    }
    if (!user.isActivated) {
      next(new Error('Please activate the account!'))
    }
  } catch (Error) {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ Error })
  }
}

module.exports = isActivated
```

I mean like let say we are having some code to connect to mongo as given below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true)
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
    mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true)
    mongoose.connect(process.env.URL)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('mongodb connection successful')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('mongodb connection error', err)
      })
}
```

So if we want to convert this to follow an object-oriented **design pattern** then we would have to convert **mongoose connection** to a **singleton** class so that no more than once instance can be created. Similarly, I just want to know that how could I implement the **middleware** following some design **patterns**?

Singleton class for mongo connect (example)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
class Connection {
  constructor () {
    console.log('DATABSE_URL ', process.env.DATABASE_URL)
    this.url = `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`
  }

  connect () {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true)
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
    mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true)
    mongoose.connect(this.url)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('mongodb connection successful')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('mongodb connection error', err)
      })
  }
}

// SINGLETON CLASS
class Singleton {
  constructor () {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new Connection()
    }
  }

  getInstance () {
    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
module.exports = Singleton
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. What would it mean for this to be “object oriented”? Unrelated but checking again for “user” after you just checked for “!user” is redundant.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton Yup, I got your point, I have update the question with one example. Could you please check it once again?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? What benefit does it provide? Just because something *can* be written as a class doesn't mean it *should* be. Knowing *why* is one step on the way to understanding *how*.

Comment: Hey, @DaveNewton I am new to design pattern. But one benefit that I observed after converting the mongoose connection part was that it would not create more than one instance of connection. So that's the benefit I got after implementing a singleton class for connection. But I am not sure about using design patterns in middleware. So what would you suggest for middlewares??

Comment: A function, just like you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the class as a single instance in other modules try:
module.exports = new Connection();

Comment: yeap, But that's not the solution of the question I have asked. I asked for converting the middleware to use an object-oriented design pattern